# Installing Dell R710 from Scratch

Tags: virtualization, raid, vmware-esxi, dell-poweredge, dell-perc

I am building a Dell R710 server from scratch. I am deploying a bootable USB on the internal usb port. The bootable usb contains esxi 6.x and I can't seem to configure the RAID controller from scratch. When booting (before it boots to ESXI on BIOS version 6.6), the only options I have are: F2 - System Setup, F10 - System Services, F11 - BIOS Boot Manager and F12 - PXE Boot. None of those options seem to allow me to configure a RAID controller except under the Dell Unified Server Configurator, which when I select configure RAID, it tells me no RAID controller is found.

Bottom-line, I need to configure my six 2TB SSD harddrives to be used by the ESXI running on the bootable USB in the internal USB port.

Comment: Dumb question... does the server have a RAID controller?

Comment: I mean, not a dumb question....... I'm clearly new to this and looking for help. It has a PERC H700 RAID Controller, but the option to manage it usually "Ctrl+R" isn't available during boot.

Answer (score 1):

CTRL-R only works in BIOS mode.

In UEFI mode, you need to press F2 to enter System Setup. Then click on System Setup Main Menu screen and then click on Device Settings. There you will find the PREC settings.

Make your RAIDs, save the settings, then boot and start installing ESXi.